# Transparent page in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I need to be able to create a transparent Xamarin.Forms page for Android. How can I do this true a page renderer? Now it has a default background color.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyPage), typeof(ClearBackgroundPageRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    public class ClearBackgroundPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            SetBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent.ToAndroid());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) ! Please read  [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) !

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to make your page's background transparent, you don't need to create a custom renderer for this. You can set the background color in PCL.

For example, xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NameSpace"
             x:Class="NameSpace.MainPage"
             BackgroundColor="Transparent">

</ContentPage>
```

Or in code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
    }
}
```

To prove it's transparent, we can use a `NavigationPage` with colored background for testing in `App.xaml.cs`:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage())
    {
        BackgroundColor = Color.Red
    };
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. You can't make the Background color tranparent

Comment: @BenBtg, the problem was to make a contentpage control transparent, not the whole application, so in my answer, the contentpage is wrapped by `NavigationPage`, so when to navigate to the content page with transparent background, it will show the background of NavigationPage. Why said it doesn't work? Is there any update version which disables this function?

Comment: It doesn't work. You can set it to any other color but NOT Transparent!