# MAUI between windows' navigation

Tags: c#, .net, maui, maui-windows, .net-maui.shell

Im develop desktop tray app via WPF and Im intersted in MAUI, but I dont have any idea how to implement navigation from one window to another like from page to page.

There is Shell class which implies that app must have mainpage on the top of navigation stack. But in my case app's ui have several entry points to app's UI like dropzone, global keyboard handler (hotkeys) and tray, and there is no mainpage like in a mobile app or in others single window apps.

Im looking for a way to navigate between dropzone/tray, settings menu, some overlays, and edtitors/previews.

Maybe Im missing something important or its really looks a bit far-fetched to try transfer app with such type of architecture into MAUI framework.

Comment: One Maui app can have [multiple windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/windows?view=net-maui-7.0#multi-window-support) you can use C# events to tell the app what to do with each window. Though [maui doesn't support transparancy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71928071/maui-how-to-make-the-background-color-transparent) and from what I understand the kind of app you want need that. If you don't need multi platform maui is probably a worst choice than WPF anyway.

Comment: I saw multiple windows feature in MAUI. There are even some methods for navigation, but they expose opportunity to make modal window. This is not enough. 

Unfortunately maui's cross-platform ability is one of the main reasons why Im interesed in it. MAUI allows build app's architecture and configure ui and service layer per each platform if I need.

Thank you for answer and for the link about transparency support.

Comment: In App.xaml.cs, replace `MainPage = new AppShell();` with `MainPage = new NavigationPage();`. This is a "lower level" navigation model; a bit more programming needed, but you have full control over nav stack and appearance. Remove all uses of AppShell from xaml and c#. Then use Navigation methods described in NavigationPage doc. Be sure not to use any navigation examples that assume Shell - most Maui examples assume that.

Comment: @Uporka I am very glad that we have MAUI. Mobile (IOS+Android) development is ok. There are still thousands of issues with the platform, but if I want to write something simple, and do it fast (and now when I know how to avoid most of the BIG problems), I use it. But for complex things I go native. No need of dealing with all this mess, and writing bunch of platform specific code, and wasting twice the time I need, than just creating two different projects from the start. I suggest staying at WPF for now.